# Getstream listen to channel events with error GetOrCreateChannel "When using member based IDs specify at least 2 members"

Tags: javascript, node.js, chat, listener, getstream-io

I've encountered problems while trying to listen to messages on a GetStream channel.

I want to listen to new messages from a GetStream channel in real-time for subsequent processing. The code snippet throws an error on the line **channel.watch()**. The error message is: "*When using member-based IDs specify at least 2 members*."

From what I've read, there are two ways to create or connect to a channel:

1. Through its members
2. Using the channel's unique identifier

In my case, the channel has already been created by another app previously and the channel has a channelId (i can see it on the getStream dashboard). The _channelId parameter I'm using is the unique channelId. I am sure.

Where is the error?
Thanks

```
exports.listenAndSentimentAnalisysChat = async (_channelId) => {
    // userId is like "user_back_client"
    const userId = `${config.GETSTREAM_USERID}`;
    const serverSideClient = await setGetStreamChatClient();

    // Connect as the application-level user (usually a server-side operation)
    const adminToken = serverSideClient.createToken(userId);
    serverSideClient._setUser(adminToken);

    // Initialize the channel you want to get messages from
    const channel = serverSideClient.channel("livestream", _channelId);

    // Add an event listener for new messages
    channel.on('message.new', event => {
        console.log(`Received message: ${event.message.text} from ${event.message.user.id}`);
    });

    // Connect to the channel
    await channel.watch();


}
```

We have a paid subscription, and although I've reached out to support, the response I received was quite vague and did not solve the issue. Additionally, I find the documentation to be lacking and limited.

I I want to receive the messages, but I'm getting an error.